# Using numpy, how do you calculate snowfall per month?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a data set with snowfall records per day for one year. Date variable is in YYYYMMDD form.

```
Date      Snow
20010101  0
20010102  10
20010103  5
20010104  3
20010105  0
...
20011231  0
```

The actual data is here

https://github.com/emily737373/emily737373/blob/master/COX_SNOW-1.csv

I want to calculate the number of days it snowed each month. I know how to do this with pandas, but for a school project, I need to do it only using numpy. I can not import datetime either, it must be done only using numpy.

The output should be in this form

```
    Month     # days snowed
    January   13   
    February  19
    March     20
    ...
    December  15
```

My question is how do I only count the number of days it snowed (basically when snow variable is not 0) without having to do it separately for each month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you can use some built-in packages, such as `datetime`, cause it's useful when working with datetime objects.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

df = np.genfromtxt('test_files/COX_SNOW-1.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1, dtype=str)

date = np.array([dt.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y%m%d").month for d in df[:, 0]])
snow = df[:, 1].copy().astype(np.int32)

has_snowed = snow > 0

for month in range(1, 13):
    month_str = dt.datetime(year=1, month=month, day=1).strftime('%B')
    how_much_snow = len(snow[has_snowed & (date == month)])
    print(month_str, ':', how_much_snow)
```

I loaded the data as `str` so we guarantee we can parse the `Date` column as dates later on. That's why we also need to explicitly convert the `snow` column to `int32`, otherwise the `>` comparison won't work.

The output is as follows:

```
January : 13
February : 19
March : 20
April : 13
May : 8
June : 9
July : 2
August : 7
September : 9
October : 19
November : 16
December : 15
```

Let me know if this worked for you or if you have any further questions.